# Reply to tweets don't appear in the tweet box

Tags: twitter

When I reply to someone's tweet, my replies don't show up when I open the tweet, along with other users' replies. Why?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably not using the "reply" link.

[image]

If you just type in an

> @person this is my reply

then there's no in_reply_to parameter set, which results in broken conversation. If you click on the reply link, the in_reply_to parameter is set & the thread is maintained.

Comment: I do use the reply link, from Google chrome under windows.

Comment: @Tarek put screen shots of what you're doing and how it shows up

Comment: It works for me when I do what @Sathya suggested. I use also use Google Chrome browser 18.0.1025.168 with Windows 7. Please post screen shots, so we can take a look, if you wouldn't mind. I'm curious why you would have problems, but Twitter is strange sometimes!

Comment: @Sathya a bit off topic, but in your screenshot there's a "Buffer" link. I've never seen that, what is it?

Comment: @Dez oh that's an [webapp](http://bufferapp.com) I use for scheduling my links so that my timeline doesn't get spammed with links all at once!